# Functional analysis, absolutely convex

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

> Let $E$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vectorspace. Then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> (1) $V\subseteq E$ is absolutely convex.
>
> (2) $V\subseteq E$ is convex and $\lambda V\subseteq V$ for every $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$ with $|\lambda|\leq 1$
>
> (3) $V\subseteq E$ is convex and $\lambda V\subseteq V$ for every $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$ with $\lambda=0$ or $|\lambda|=1$

Obviously it is $(2)\Rightarrow (3)$.

When the statement holds for every $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$ with $|\lambda|\leq 1$ then also for every $\lambda$ with $\lambda=0$ and $|\lambda|=1$.

I might have some twist here, but $(3)\Rightarrow (2)$ should be also obvious, since $(3)$ implies that the statement holds only(?) for $\lambda$ with $\lambda=0$ and $|\lambda|=1$, hence $|\lambda|\leq 1$.

Which leaves us with showing $(1)\Leftrightarrow (2)$ or $(3)$.

$(1)\Rightarrow (3)$

Let $V\subseteq E$ be absolutely convex. Then $V$ is obviously convex.
For $\lambda=0$ we have $0\cdot V=\{0\}\subseteq V$.
If $|\lambda|=1$, then let $v\in\lambda V$. Hence $v=\lambda v'$ where $v'\in V$. Since $V$ is convex for all $x,y\in V$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$ it is $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\in V$. For $x=v'$ and $y=0$ we get $\lambda v'=v\in V$

$(3)\Rightarrow (1)$

Let $V\subseteq E$ be convex and $\lambda V\subseteq V$ for every $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$ with $\lambda=0$ and $|\lambda|=1$.

We have to show, that $V$ is absolutley convex.
Hence: For $x_1,\dotso, x_n\in V$ and $\lambda_1,\dotso, \lambda_n\in\mathbb{K}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|\leq 1$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_ix_i\in V$

Here I am kinda stuck.
Do you have a hint on how to proceed?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(3) \Rightarrow (2)$ isn't as trivial as you make it seem. You have to combine the fact that $\lambda V \subset V$ holds for $\lvert \lambda \rvert =1$ or $0$ with the convexity in order to prove that $\lambda V \subset V$ holds for all $\lvert \lambda \rvert \leq 1$.

In $(1) \Rightarrow (3)$ you say that $\lambda \in [0,1]$. This of course doesn't need to be the case, what if $\lambda = -1$ or some imaginary number?

To prove $(3) \Rightarrow (1)$,
it's sufficient to prove that for any $x, y \in V$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{K}$ with $\lvert \alpha \rvert + \lvert \beta \rvert \leq 1$ we have $\alpha x + \beta y \in V$. Now take $\theta, \varphi$ such that $\alpha = \lvert \alpha \rvert e^{i\theta}$ and $\beta = \lvert \beta \rvert e^{i \varphi}$. By property $(3)$ we have that $e^{i \theta} x \in V$ and $e^{i \varphi} y \in V$. By convexity of $V$ we then have that 
$$
\alpha x + \beta y = \lvert \alpha \rvert e^{i \theta} x + \lvert \beta \rvert e^{i\varphi}y \in V,
$$
proving that $V$ is absolutely convex.

Comment: I am still struggeling with $(3)\Rightarrow (2)$. So I want to show, that $\kappa V\subseteq V$ for with $\kappa\in\mathbb{K}$ and $|\kappa|\leq 1$. Let $v\in\kappa V$. Then $v=\kappa\cdot v'$ where $v'\in V$. Now I do not really see how I can use the convexity of $V$ to go on. Neither do I see how to use, that the statement holds for $\lambda=0$ or $|\lambda|=1$.

Comment: Since $0 \cdot V \subset V$, you have $0 \in V$. Now because $\lvert \kappa \rvert \leq 1$ you have $\lvert \kappa \rvert v + (1-\lvert \kappa \rvert) \cdot 0 = \lvert \kappa \rvert v \in V$ by the convexity of $V$. Then take $\theta$ such that $\kappa = e^{i\theta} \lvert \kappa \rvert$ holds. We know $\lvert \kappa \rvert v \in V$ and $\lvert e^{i\theta} \rvert =1$ so we must have $\kappa v= e^{i\theta} \lvert \kappa \rvert v \in V$.

Comment: Thank you. I somehow ignored the fact, that I can use $|\kappa|\leq 1$ too...

Comment: Could you give a hint on how to proof $(1)\Rightarrow (3)$?

Comment: Write down the definition of absolutely convex, i.e. $\forall y,z \in V: \forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{K}: \lvert \alpha \rvert +\lvert \beta\rvert \leq 1 \Rightarrow \alpha y + \beta z \in V$. Now choose your $\alpha, \beta$ and $y,z$ appropriately such that you can conclude that $\lambda x \in V$